# Ionic ion-refresh works for android and web but not iOS

Tags: ionic-framework

I've reserached through many solved questions for the ion-refresher, but it still does not work for my application. I've upgraded Ionic to the latest versions as the bugs for the refresher seemed to be fixed, but it still does not work for me.

Within the Web and MD Version the refresher works just fine, but the iOS Version is buggy and has several errors

- at first, it does not even show
- when refreshing, it seems that the event never finishes
- the refresher is not there on init for the component, but becomes visible
  if i scroll around or move back and forward, but neither those actions are   constant.

> ```
> "@ionic-native/core": "^5.34.0",
> "@ionic/angular": "^5.6.11",
> ```

ion-refresh within the ion-content

```
   <ion-refresher
    (ionRefresh)="refresh($event)"
    slot="fixed">
    <ion-refresher-content>
    </ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>
```

refresh method

```
  public async refresh(event) {    

    // BL

    setTimeout(() => {
      event.target.complete();
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Comment: You say that "it does not even show" but then "when refreshing, it seems that the event never finishes". Is refresher not visible at first pull? Is refresher not hides for second pull?

Comment: That is exactly what happens - if i scroll a bit around or move into the component from another component, the loader suddenly appears. But on initial state, it is not there. I add it to the question

Comment: I'm not faced with problems with a refresher. Probably you use it not properly. Can you add a more detailed example of usage from your project? HTML part first of all.